# Finding eigenvalues for linear map...is this the correct approach?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A= \begin{pmatrix} a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\\ \end{pmatrix}$ $\in M_2(\mathbb R)$. Define a map $H_A :M_2(\mathbb R) \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb R)$ by $$H_A(B)= \begin{pmatrix} a_{11}b_{11}&a_{12}b_{12}\\a_{21}b_{21}&a_{22}b_{22}\\ \end{pmatrix}$$ for all $B=\begin{pmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}\\ \end{pmatrix}$ $\in M_2(\mathbb R)$.

If $A= \begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}$, find the eigenvalues of $H_A$.

Would it be correct if I set $H_A(B)= \lambda B$ and solve for $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: HINT: characteristic polynomial

Answer (score 0):

Choose the basis $E_{ij}$ (zeroes everywhere except for a one in the $ij$ position) for $M_2(\mathbb R)$. Then $H_A$ has a particularly simple form in this basis, which will help with eigenvalues eigenvectors, characteristic polynomial, etc.